# Node Express Handlebars helper not returning result of function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, helper, handlebars.js

I'm baffled on this one. If I use a function within a handlebars helper and return the result of that function, nothing is returned.

Here is the template:

```
<ul>
    <li>{{formatid this.id}}</li>
</ul>
```

And here is the helper:

```
formatid : function(id){
    mOrders.formatOrderID(id, function(err, formatted_id){
        // err is always null, no need to handle
        console.log(formatted_id);
        return formatted_id;
    });
}
```

Yet despite the correct text being logged to the console, the resultant html is:

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

If, however, I put a return after the end of the formatOrderID() function, it gets returned, so this:

```
formatid : function(id){
    mOrders.formatOrderID(id, function(err, formatted_id){
        // err is always null, no need to handle
        console.log(formatted_id);
        return formatted_id;
    });
    return 'some_text';
}
```

gives me the following html:

```
<ul>
    <li>some_text</li>
</ul>
```

What am I missing here? It's not the returned formatted string, as even when I return a string within the callback it's ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to return a value from an asynchronous function, but handlebars helpers are synchronous. By the time the callback passed in `mOrders.formatOrderID()` gets executed your helper function already exited (with value `undefined`, since you didn't return anything outside the callback in your first example, and with `'some_text'` in your second example).

One solution is to make `mOrders.formatOrderID` be synchronous (if possible or feasible) or use a library like [express-hbs](https://github.com/barc/express-hbs) and define [asynchronous helpers](https://github.com/barc/express-hbs#helpers) like this:

```
var hbs = require('express-hbs');

hbs.registerAsyncHelper('formatid', function(id, cb) {
  mOrders.formatOrderID(id, function(err, formatted_id){
    // err is always null, no need to handle
    console.log(formatted_id);
    cb(formatted_id);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. That makes perfect sense. I made the function synchronous. For some reason I had it in my head that the callback and the lack of return outside would make it blocking. I see now that's just silly ;)